# Directory and segments in Multics operating system

Tags: linux, unix, permissions, operating-systems, multics

In Multics OS there are different access rights in the access control list for segments (*execute, read and write*) and directories (*status, append and modify*)([book](http://www.cse.psu.edu/~tjaeger/cse443-s12/docs/ch3.pdf)).

How do segments correspond to directories, and why there are different access rights for each([AL39](http://www.multicians.org/AL39.pdf))? Are directories stored as segments or not?I add tags of unix and linux because of the similarity among them.

Comment: Wow, looks like you're working with an [antique OS](http://web.mit.edu/multics-history/). Only 12 posts here at [su] mention it.

Comment: The questioner is taking a [course on computer security](http://www.cse.psu.edu/~tjaeger/cse443-s12/) which includes a history lesson.

Comment: According to ftp://ftp.stratus.com/vos/multics/pg/mvm.html , directories are ring 0 segments. There were other types of segments, too, such as message segments, which had access permissions a d r o s and w.